# Python Nested, Nested FOR LOOP, mixed up

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

there.

Maybe I can't see the forest for the trees or totally mixed up in this thing.
But I want have the array `x` with the shape of `(120, 68,815)`.

```
epochs = 120
channels = 68
samples = 815
```

I want to calculate for every epoch every channel with every channel so:
Epoch 1: Channel 1 with 1 with 2 with 3 and so on.
The same for every epoch.

When I run the code like explained below, I always get the same values for EVERY epoch.
I think there is a mistake in the loop but I could not find it.
Anyone experienced enough to find it ?

```
Rxy = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs), dtype=complex)
Rxx = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs))
Ryy = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs))
for i in range(0, n_epochs):
    print('Computed Epoch %s'%(i+1))
    for j in xrange(0, channels):
        for k in xrange(0, channels):
            Rxy[i,j,k], freqs = mlab.csd(x[j], x[k], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
            Rxx[i,j,k], _____ = mlab.psd(x[j], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
            Ryy[i,j,k], _____ = mlab.psd(x[k], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)

    Rxy_mean = np.mean(Rxy, axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
    Rxx_mean = np.mean(Rxx, axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
    Ryy_mean = np.mean(Ryy, axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
```

Thank you.

Comment: for k in xrange(0, channels): should be for k in xrange(0, samples), no ?

Comment: No! The k loop is necessary to run and calculate every channel start in in the j loop with every channel in the k loop. Because we use the k loop and all the samples are stored in this array, we don't need to especially run the number of n_freqs.

Comment: Change your variable names:  instead of `i`, `j`, and `k`, name them something that communicates their purpose.  That helps a lot, especially when you come back to read the code tomorrow, next week, next month, or a year from now or when someone else looks at it and asks "what was he thinking!?".

Comment: producing a [mcve] may yield some solutions. Also reading [ask] may be beneficial.

Comment: @boardrider No thank you. Everyone got the problem. There is no need to investigate those links. I also already figured out how to do it properly.

Comment: If you `already figured out how to do it properly` you may want to answer your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I was really busy. The answer/solution is coming right up.

Answer (score 0):

So I just changed the array form in my function to not calculate all the channels cross each other in the function, but outside with the itertool.
It creates all possible combination of the 68 channels and runs the compute[...]-function on every of those combination storing it in an appropriate array form.

```
def compute_mean_psd_csd(x, y, n_epochs, nfft, sfreq):
    '''Computes mean of PSD and CSD for signals.'''
    Rxy = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=np.complex)
    Rxx = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=np.complex)
    Ryy = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=np.complex)
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        Rxy[i], freqs = mlab.csd(x[i], y[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
        Rxx[i], _ = mlab.psd(x[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
        Ryy[i], _ = mlab.psd(y[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)

    Rxy_mean = np.mean(Rxy, axis=0)
    Rxx_mean = np.mean(Rxx, axis=0)
    Ryy_mean = np.mean(Ryy, axis=0)

    return freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean, np.real(Rxx_mean), np.real(Ryy_mean)

import itertools
comb = itertools.combinations(range(channels), 2)
for m, n in comb:
    freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean = compute_mean_psd_csd(x[:, n, :], x[:, m, :], n_epochs, nfft, sfreq)
    assert len(freqs) == n_freqs, 'n_freqs do not match. Check nfft values provided.'
```

The changes do reduce my running time to "just" 250 seconds.
Any questions ?!